# Importing only specific columns from CSV file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to import CSV files using Java library openCSV. Is there any way to load only specific columns not all of them? My code right now is:

```
JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "CSV file", "csv");
                fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Choose file");
                                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
        File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getName());
        File csvFilename = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
        try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'',11 )) {
            String[] row = null;
            while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println(row[0]
                        + " # " + row[1]
                        + " #  " + row[2]);
            }
        } 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Glass_search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Glass_search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    }
```

This file also got headings so maybe this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular case [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) is a much better fit as you can easily choose what columns to get:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(); //detects the format 

//extracts the headers from the input
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

//or give the header names yourself
// if you use this it will override the headers read from the input (enabled above).
settings.setHeaders("A", "B", "C");

//now for the column selection
settings.selectFields("A", "C"); //rows will contain only values of column "A" and "C"
//or
settings.selectIndexes(0, 2); //rows will contain only values of columns at position 0 and 2

List<String[]> rows = new CsvParser(settings).parseAll(new File("/path/to/your.csv"), "UTF-8");
```

You can also get the values of each column in a `List`:

```
ColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
settings.setProcessor(columnProcessor);
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.parse(new File("/path/to/your.csv), "UTF-8"); //all rows are submitted to the processor created above.

Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = columnProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

This should solve all your problems, hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: First one works just perfect, now I'm trying to use file from JFileChooser and upload it to MSSQL database :) Thank you.
Your library saved me a lot work.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your CSVReader instance using a CSVReaderBuilder you can set your own parser for the reader to use. All you need then is to create your own parser that implements the ICSVParser interface.

Comment: ahh crap, that's not my level of exp yet ;) Thanks anyway